# Application Fail to start correctly error

Tags: c++, cen-xfs

I'm developing an application using Wosa/XFS and the current problem is that it produce and error on startup saying "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click Ok to close the application."

This is produced by Wfs_Startup call.

BOOL Wfs_Startup(void)
{
WFSVERSION WfsVersion;
return (WFSStartUp(RECOGNISED_VERSIONS,
                     &WfsVersion) == WFS_SUCCESS);
}

I don't know what may be the course of this error whether it because I didn't load the NI_XFSMgr.DLL or it the 3 DLL files that I put on System32 directory.

Anyone with a knowledge on WOSA/XFS please help me out with the solution. My application is console based at the moment.

I thank you.

Comment: Thanks and yes indeed I've just checked my registry and there is no xfs key there, so how can I solve this? Mean how I should create the key and memory shared and what must I write there? Thanks again.

Comment: :-) I've just created a VM and installed another instence of an OS then I recreated my application then installed the XFS and used the registry that came with the WOSA XFS to update the current system registry then this solved the problem. Thanks again for your help now my app can execute correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may occur when you haven't configure xfs registry correctly.
Check your `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\XFS\XFS_MANAGER` node.

All values must be correct.

Another reason may be your application has no access to **xfs shared memory file**.

Path to shared memory file is set at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\XFS\XFS_MANAGER` ShareFileName parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an XFS problem.
This is due to the DLLs you put in to the system32 folder not being signed or digitally no longer valid.
More info and a trick to go pass this can be found from [here](http://deshack.net/windows-how-to-solve-application-error-0xc0000142-and-0xc0000005/)

The easier solution would be to put those DLLs in the folder where your application is (And that to be outside of system32).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've done as per your suggestion but still the problem hasn't been solved.